# How to add required to model property in controller mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model `CompanyInfoModel` It has such field:

```
[Display(Name = "CompanyName", ResourceType = typeof(i18n))]
[StringLength(64, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(i18n), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidCompanyLength")]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

In controller, in a get method under certain condition I must make property `CompanyName` required (This property is not always required). I cannot add required property in view because of custom implementation of `@Html.EditorFor`.

How can I add `required` attribute to the property in the controller?

Comment: What are the circumstances that make the field required, as this has an effect on the answer?

Comment: Is 'Required` based on the value of another property in your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **conditional validation** You have a few options here

1) Create a custom required attribute, and implement the logic that is required to turn required field on / off

```
public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override IsValid(object val, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if(SomeConditionisValid())
             return base.IsValid(val, context);
        else
             return true; // the field is valid (e.g not required)
    }
}
```

This can be used to drive the validation if the rules can be derived from the model.  The model will be available from **ValidationContext.ObjectInstance**

2)  Instead of the above you can implement **IValidatableObject** which provides a method you can implement to perform validation rules during model binding.  Again if you can derive the validation rules wholly from the validated object.

On your model, implement **IValidatableObject**

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
    ValidationContext validationContext
     if(SomethingIsInvalid())
         yield return new ValidationResult("Something is invalid") { }
)
```

3) If you need context from outside of the model to perform validation, Do the validation in a custom model binder, e.g  inherit from **DefaultModelBinder**  and override

```
protected virtual bool OnPropertyValidating(
    ControllerContext controllerContext,
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor,
    Object value
)
{
    if(SomethingIsInvalid())
    {
         bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Field", "Is Required");
    }

    base.OnPropertyValidating(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor)
}
```

Then register the model binder for the type

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(CompanyInfoModelBinder))]
public class CompanyInfoModel
{

}
```

4) Do it in the controller (not recommended!)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I haven't used it, but I think it will be useful for someone, so you get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view model:

```
public class CompanyInfoViewModel {
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Add whatever other info you need in that view model, and either use the view model as the parameter type for your post action or create a custom model binder that will map the view model back to the domain model.

Answer (score 0):

I have found other way of doing this with JQuery. I just run

```
$("#CompanyName").prop('required',true);
```

when I need it.

Comment: Don't forget that jqyery is client side and the user can always overcome this type of validation, and thus your CompanyName becomes not validated... Always validate server side.